# NSNotificationCenter - UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification takes too long

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter

My code:

```
overide func viewDidLoad() {
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "activeAgain", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object:nil)
}

func activeAgain() {
   println("ActiveAgain") //Comes immediately
   callSeparateFunction() //Takes 5s
}
```

Why does the println comes immediately and the separate function call takes up to 5s? I have to call a new function when the app comes back to foreground. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean `call takes up to 5s` ? How are you testing that? What does the function do?

Comment: Do you mean the time between the println and the call to your function? What does your function do? Maybe your function is blocking or something, put println in your function to see when it being called. And post the code of your function for more informztion